# How do pilots of Deep Sea Vehicles operate the control surfaces and thrusters from inside a pressure hull?

Tags: oceanography

A Deep Sea Vehicle (DSV) like Trieste or Limiting Factor or now Fundouzhe have control thrusters, ballast that has to be dumped, and other equipment to operate the DSVs.

But the pressure hull is a solid sphere minus the porthole windows and a hatch?

How does the pilot control these systems? Is there some conduits cut through the pressure hull? Optical penetrators could be used but how does this not compromise the integrity of the pressure hull? How else might it be done?

Comment: This question sounds more fit for something like Operations Research but doesn't sound fit for Earth Science.

Comment: OR is about decision making. There are only a small number of deep sea vehicles anyway with narrow operation limits. Engeneering, I believe, would be a better fit.

Comment: how do high altitude planes do it,they have the same type of problem how to keep pressure on the right side of the hull.this question might be a better fit over at https://engineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @trondhansen I just want to keep all my deep sea stuff in one spot. It's damaging the discipline to have to scatter it everywhere. Space exploration doesn't have this problem they have their own site. As for your question, it's a lot easier to punch a hole through a fuselage than a pressure hull. Holes cause weakpoints and I'm curious how they build the pressure hulls for deep ocean.

Comment: Cross posted, with two answer on [SE Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/43024/how-do-pilots-of-deep-sea-vehicles-operate-the-control-surfaces-and-thrusters-fr)